# dynamic label with textbox entered value on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textbox in html page; I want that when a user types something into the textbox and when the user hits the button (say it as Postvalue), it should post the value as a label with textbox value beside the textbox.

This should happen whenever user types anything and then hits the button; but, for now, I'm doing it with textbox but I want it to change with label. Can anyone help me out here?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input id="tags2" type="text" placeholder="Post Tags" />
<button onclick="getwords()">Post</button>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function getwords() {
    var textbox = document.createElement('input');

    textbox.setAttribute('type', 'label');

    textbox.setAttribute("readOnly", "true");

    document.getElementById('textpost').appendChild(textbox).value = document.getElementById("tags2").value;

  }
```

Comment: On clicking the `<button>` the user-entered value should be added to the page (before, or after, the existing `<input>`)? Do you want that text wrapped in a `<label>` element, or do you just want it to be text? Before you answer, please check what a [`<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is, and should (*only*) be, used for, because it's *not* just a piece of text, it should be uniquely associated with a specific form-element (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`). Incidentally, a `<label>` is an element, it's not a 'type' of an `<input>`.

Comment: Can you explain a little better, maybe tell us what's not happening?

Comment: now when i enter something in textbox and when i press post button it comes as read only textbox with entered text as post.i want text wrapped in a <label> element means i want to post my textbox value as label.

Comment: It is something like facebook status post...write something into the textbox and press  post button ...but instead of coming inside the dynamic textbox with value it should come as label..